# Querying mongodb and trying to get result to display in index.pug, get [object Object]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get data from a mongodb in a pug/html page, and I'm close but not quite there. I've got the relevant node and mongo servers running.

The sample data I've got is

```
[ { _id: 59708077c9412f6d7f7e8485,
username: 'xyz123',
email: 'xyz123@test.com' } ]
```

And when I console log this, it appears on the node terminal window.

The code in my app.js is

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/questiondb';

var mongotest = [];

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var str = db.collection('usercollection').find();
        str.each(function (err, doc) {
                mongotest.push(doc); //Push result onto results_array
                                console.log(mongotest)

        });

                app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                    res.render('index', {"results": mongotest });


                });

            });
```

and in my index.pug file i've got

```
  p Hello
    each mongotest, i in results
      div Result #{i} #{mongotest}
```

The result in the html page is

```
Result [object Object]
```

I'm assuming I've got to change the result from an object to a string. When I use something like JSON.stringify, I renders each separate letter from the query as a separate iteration through loop in pug.

I'm close but there is obviously a hole in my learning :-)

Thanks in advance

Fixed

For those wondering, these are the changes I made to my code to get it working. I saved the property into a variable, and referenced that in the pug template.

```
var readVar;
                readVar = mongotest[0].username;

    });
};

            app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                res.render('index', { readVar});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.find() method is async method.
You should use it like this:

```
db.collection('usercollection').find({}, callback);

function callback(err, docs){
    if(err) { /*errorHandler*/ };
    docs.each(function (err, doc) {
        if(err) { /*errorHandler*/ }
        mongotest.push(doc); //Push result onto results_array
        console.log(mongotest)
    });
};
```

Dont forget to handle errors inside the callbacks

Comment: Thanks for that, well noted.I've made that change, but still nothing coming through. I've referenced a set username from the object to a variable, and passed that variable through to the pug template, but I don't get anything thing. It logs properly in the nodejs console...

Comment: Actually, just figured it out. I will update my question with the answer for others, thanks for your help!